# why does macports "--set ipython ipython32" fail?

Tags: macports, ipython

When I run `sudo port select --set ipython ipython32` -- after having successfully installed python32 and ipython32 -- do I get the following error?

```
Selecting 'ipython32' for 'ipython' failed: could not create new link \
"/opt/local/share/man/man1/ipcluster.1.gz": \
target "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2\
/share/man/man1/ipcluster.1.gz" doesn't exist
```

OK, so the error is described plainly enough ... question is: how to resolve it? Shouldn't the doc file have been part of the (successfully installed_ ipython32 package?
Things seem to work .... or should I say: I haven't *yet* hit the consequences of this failure message whilst using ipython.

Comment: A man page is documentation. The only consequence should be if you want to do `man ipcluster`.